# componentDidMount seems not to be called after setState in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

Learning ReactJS I am working on a simple countdown app. The Countdown component looks like this:

```
const Countdown = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      remaining: 10,
      running: true,
    };
  },
  componentDidMount: function(){
    if (this.state.running) {
      setInterval(this.tick, 1000);
    } else {
      console.log("already paused");
    };
  },
  tick: function(){
    if (this.state.remaining === 0) {
      this.setState({ remaining: 10 });
      this.props.updateStats();
    } else {
        this.setState({ remaining: this.state.remaining -1 });
    };

  },
  handlePauseClick: function(){
    this.setState({ running: false });
  },
  render: function(){
    const s = this.state.remaining;
    return (
      <div className='ui centered card'>
        <div className='content centered'>
          <h1>{helpers.secondsToHuman(s)}</h1>
          <ButtonControls
            handlePauseClick={this.handlePauseClick}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  },
});
```

The countdown starts running. When clicking on the pause button it is supposed to stop. The componentDidMount only runs the timer when running is true:

```
if (this.state.running) {
  setInterval(this.tick, 1000);
} else {
  console.log("already paused");
};
```

After handling the click with:

```
this.setState({ running: false });
```

I was expecting that the component gets re-rendered and that componentDidMount will be executed again. This is not happening though. componentDidMount seems only to run once.

Thanks for your ideas

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[componentDidMount](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) gets executed only once, when the React component is mounted to the tree, that's why it is not called after `setState`.

So you need [componentDidUpdate](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate), this callback gets executed on every rerender except for the initial one. For the initial one you may want to use [componentDidMount](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount).

Also, you are not clearing the interval in the `else` block, which means that the `tick` function will not stop executing even if the component is rerendered again.

---

Try this

```
componentDidMount: function() {
   this.tickInterval = setInterval(this.tick, 1000);
},

componentDidUpdate: function() {
  // if app is running and there is no tickInterval yet, set it
  if (this.state.running && this.tickInterval === null) {
    this.tickInterval = setInterval(this.tick, 1000);
  // if app is stopped, but there is a tickInterval, clear it
  } else if (!this.state.running && this.tickInterval !== null) {
    clearInterval(this.tickInterval);
    this.tickInterval = null;
  }
},

componentWillUnmount() { 
  clearInterval(this.tickInterval);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @leo. Didn't know about componentDidUpdate. It is still not working properly though.  Can it be that the interval from componentDidMount is not being stopped at all?

Comment: I've edited my answer, check it out and try to adjust to your needs.

Comment: Thank you. Now intervals seem to be created, exponentially and not cleared. I'll play around with it.

Comment: OK, once again updated the answer... but yes, play around, you are close.

Comment: Thanks, got it to work now. 
    if (!this.state.running) {
      clearInterval(this.tickInterval, 1000);
    } else {
        clearInterval(this.tickInterval, 1000);
        this.tickInterval = setInterval(this.tick, 1000);
    };

Comment: nice, great job. See I added one last line to my answer - don't forget to clean up the interval on `componentWillUnmount`

Answer (score 1):

`componentDidMount` is only executed when the initial render process is finished. You should use `componentWillUpdate` or `componentDidUpdate` for your task.